# JNA KeyboardUtils.isPressed not working with arrow keys

Tags: java, winapi, jna

I'm trying to create a sample that calls JNA's `KeyboardUtils` class to check key states on Windows (similar to Win32's `GetAsyncKeyState()`).

Here's my code:

```
package com.foo;

import com.sun.jna.platform.KeyboardUtils;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Watching for Left/Right/Up/Down or WASD.  Press Shift+Q to quit");
                while (true) {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                        if (KeyboardUtils.isPressed(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) || KeyboardUtils.isPressed(KeyEvent.VK_S) )
                        {
                            System.out.println("Down");
                        }
                        if (KeyboardUtils.isPressed(KeyEvent.VK_UP) || KeyboardUtils.isPressed(KeyEvent.VK_W) )
                        {
                            System.out.println("Up");
                        }
                        if (KeyboardUtils.isPressed(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) || KeyboardUtils.isPressed(KeyEvent.VK_A) )
                        {
                            System.out.println("Left");
                        }
                        if (KeyboardUtils.isPressed(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) || KeyboardUtils.isPressed(KeyEvent.VK_D) )
                        {
                            System.out.println("Right");
                        }
                        if (KeyboardUtils.isPressed(KeyEvent.VK_Q) && KeyboardUtils.isPressed(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT) )
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    { }
                }
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

This works fine and detects WASD keys, as well as Shift+Q.  However, the arrow keys Left/Right/Up/Down are never detected.

Converting the code to C++ and calling Win32 `GetAsyncKeyState()` does work with the arrow keys.

According to the web, the value of [`KeyEvent.VK_DOWN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) matches the [Win32 definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) (40).

Any idea why JNA isn't correctly detecting the arrow keys?

Comment: I have yet to see a valid use case for `GetAsyncKeyState`. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @IInpectable - My use case is to read the key state in immediate mode, rather than using KeyEvents from awt or swing.  That's the purpose of GetAsyncKeyState (which is what isPressed calls on Windows).

Comment: I understand, what `GetAsyncKeyState` does. I do not understand, why you (or anyone) would want to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`KeyboardUtils` source code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/java-native-access/jna/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/KeyboardUtils.java), **`KeyboardUtils` does not support arrow keys at all, on any platform.**

`KeyboardUtils` is implemented for only 3 keyboard platforms - Windows, Mac, and Linux.

On Mac, `isPressed()` is not implemented at all and returns false for all key codes, and an `UnsupportedOperationException` is thrown when `KeyboardUtils` is initialized.

On Windows and Linux, `KeyboardUtils` supports the following keys:

- `VK_A` - `VK_Z`
- `VK_0` - `VK_9`
- `VK_SHIFT`
- `VK_CONTROL`
- `VK_ALT`
- `VK_META` (Linux only)

On Windows, `KeyboardUtils.isPressed()` translates `KeyEvent` key codes into Win32 virtual key codes (in `W32KeyboardUtils.toNative()`) and passes them to `GetAsyncKeyState()` (in `W32KeyboardUtils.isPressed()`). But arrow keys are not handled and get translated to virtual key code 0, which is not a valid key code.

Similar with Linux key codes.

So, to detect arrow keys on Windows, you will have to call `GetAsyncKeyState()` yourself, as you have already discovered.